# How to exclude item from collapse in bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have been wanting to exclude a certain item on the navbar from the collapse box when the screen becomes small.

This is the HTML code I have so far:

```
    <div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="."><img class="ico_img" src="assets/ico_img.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="page3.php">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
          <li><a class="welcome"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I would like to exclude the welcome part. One solution I have found thus far is by adding the 'hidden-xs' class attribute to hide the welcome message when the collapse toggle appears, but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK that's the cleanest way. What would be cleaner that adding 1 CSS class?

Comment: Well I thought maybe it would be the positioning in HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a bunch of .visibble-*-*. It's cleaner with an .hidden-xs.